# Did a Hutt Jedi exist in canon?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Around 2010-2012, I read on an online forum that there was at least one Hutt in the Jedi order at one point. However, looking up 'Hutt Jedi' on google more recently, I've read people saying the idea of Hutt Jedi was strictly a legends/EU thing, and a widely disparaged one at that.

In modern canon, was there ever a Hutt Jedi?

Comment: The legends Hutt Jedi was 
Beldorion, in the legends canon they were seen as the only Hutt jedi https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beldorion

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. The sole example of a Hutt *Jedi* appears to be [Beldorion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beldorion), who makes an appearance in the 1997 EU novel [Planet of Twilight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Planet_of_Twilight), and various sources connected with this book.

[image]

Interestingly, there was also a Hutt *Sith acolyte* called [Gamblor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gamblor), but he was a fictional character *within* the Star Wars universe, appearing on a holovid show called '*Juo Deltar Faces Gamblor the Terrible*'.

Comment: Gamblor?  The Simpsons really do do everything first.